# Cauchy-Riemann Conditions-Multivariable Taylor Series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

[image: Click here to see the image]

İ didn't understood the last step.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is hidden in the binomial theorem. The second sigma term is a binominal expansion and notting else.